# How to maintain Alpakka/Akka Streams source state across application restarts?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, alpakka

I am new to Alpakka and am considering using it for system integration. What would be the ideal way to maintain the state of the Akka Streams sources across application restarts ?

For example: let's assume I'm using something as follows to continuously read some input data and dump it somewhere. What if it runs for like 4h, then the full JVM crashes and restarts (e.g. k8s restarts my pod or so):

```
someSource
    .via(someTransformation)
    .via(someOtherTransformation)
    .toMap(...)
    .run()
```

I understand that if `someSource` is a Kafka source or Kinesis source or some other stateful source, they can keep track of their offset or checkpoint and restart more or less where they left off.

However, many other sources have no such concept, e.g. the Cassandra source, the File source or the RDBMs source. For example, if I shutdown and restart the code provided in the [rdms example](https://akka.io/alpakka-samples/jdbc-to-elasticsearch/step_001_complete.html#data-class-and-json-mapping-for-elasticsearch), it will restart from the top each time.

Am I understanding correctly that there is no mechanism to address that out of the box, s.t. we have to handle it manually ? I would have imagined that this feature would be desired so commonly that it would be handled somehow. If not, how do people typically address that ? Do you use Akka persistence to store some cursors in a few actors? Or do you store the origin offset together with the output data and re-read it on startup?

Or am I looking at all this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

It is a feature that is extremely commonly desired, for the reason you suggest.

However, the only generic, reliable way to implement this would be using akka persistence which is probably the single heaviest (e.g. it requires choosing a database) dependency in the Akka ecosystem.  Beyond that, it's going to be somewhat source specific.  Some (e.g. Kafka, Kinesis) have a means of doing this that's going to fit the bill in nearly every scenario, but for the others, the details of how to store the state of consumption are something on which there will be a lot of differences of opinion.  Akka and Alpakka in general tend to shy away from opinionation.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Levi. Ok, I guess it makes sense, a unified way would be tricky to achieve across technologies. I think the approach I'll take will be to store that source state as part of the destination data. In instance, I'm reading from some HTTP streaming endpoint and pushing records to kafka. I can simply set a header in the kafka record where I store the source "cursor", and upon restart I can easily rediscover the latest successfully processed cursor.